# Python - Iterate over while loop to compile an average runtime of program

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, runtime, average, fibonacci

So I want to preface this by saying one of the biggest problems with this I'm assuming is the `return` section of this code. With that being said, exactly what I'm trying to do is based off of my previous question for this code which was answered in two different ways, one said to be faster than the other. I wanted to see just how much faster myself by comparing the numbers. The problem I am now having though is that I would like to iterate over this function X amount of times, take the runtimes for each of those executions of the code, compile them, and create an average so I can then do the same with the other proposed solution, and compare the two. The main answer or help I'm currently looking for is getting this to iterate so I can have X different runtimes available to be seen. After that I will try to figure out how to compile them on my own, unless someone would be kind enough to help me through this entire process in one go.

```
import time
start_time = time.time()


def fibonacci():
    previous_num, result = 0, 1
    user = 1000
    iterations = 10
    while len(str(result)) < user:
        while iterations != 0:
            iterations -= 1
            previous_num, result = result, previous_num + result
            print(iterations)
    return result


print(fibonacci())
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: There is the `timeit` module in the standard library which pretty much provides what you are trying to do if I understand correctly.

Comment: And what was the problem when you tried to run the function repeatedly? Did you try to use a `for` loop?